# Having problems making this program run faster for large inputs

Tags: python, performance, math, time-complexity

```
def calculate(i,j,m,k,n):
    for v in range(1,n+1):
        ans = (i*k + j) % m
        k = ans
    return ans
```

The program represents a general formula where `x = (i * k + j) % m` where `k` is the value of the previous answer. In a sense, it's basically `x1 = (i * x0 + j) % m`, and `x2 = (i * x1 + j) % m`, and so forth. The problem I'm having is that it takes a long while to calculate large inputs.

With that in mind, I was thinking along the lines of using an arithmetic series formula such as: `a + (n - 1) * d)`, but I'm unsure on how to implement it in a program such as this.

Comment: Can you please correct the indentation in the sample code? Python is very dependent on indentation, and it's hard to tell what this code is supposed to mean. The Python compiler will probably complain about the inconsistent indentation too.

Comment: Rewrite the two loop lines as `k = (i*k + j) % m`, this will save you an assignment statement. And how large is _large_?

Comment: @DYZ Like n = 1000000000

Comment: Looks like this is an unfair task for Python. The same program in C takes 2 seconds.

Comment: To clarify on the problem above: For example, i = 3, j = 5, m = 10, k = 1, n = 3 then
 (i * k + j) % m = (3*(1) + 5) % 10 = 8 (1st Iteration),
                 
   (3*(8) + 5) % 10 = 9 (2nd Iteration),

 (3*(9) + 5) % 10 = 2 (3rd Iteration)

And then the program would output 2 as its result

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you encounter this problem? Time-constrained operations with exact results from modulo arithmetic sounds very much like some kind of programming contest.

Comment: @MvG well, it's not a contest per se. It's a problem my teacher developed and then he put it on Hackerrank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x1 = (i * x0 + j)
x2 = (i * x1 + j) = i * i * x0 + i * j + j
x3 = i * i * i * x0 + i * i * j + i * j + j
xn = i^n * x0 + sum(i^t for t from 0 to n - 1) * j
   = i^n * x0 + (i^n - 1) / (i - 1) * j
```

Found the last line [with Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+i%5Et+for+t+from+0+to+n-1&rawformassumption=%22i%22+-%3E+%22Variable%22).

The formula is nice if `m` is a prime.
In that case you can perform all the computations modulo that prime,
including the division, to keep the numbers small.
You'd just need to get exponentiation `i^n` fast.
I suggest you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method and references therein.
This should give you O(log(*n*)) time complexity, compared to the O(*n*) of your loop.

If `m` is not a prime, the division in the above formula is annoying. But you can do something similar to exponentiation by squaring to compute the sum, too. Observe

```
1 + i + i^2 + i^3 + i^4 + i^5 + i^6 + … + i^(2n+1) =
(1 + i) * (1 + i^2 + i^4 + i^6 + … + i^n)
1 + i + i^2 + i^3 + i^4 + i^5 + i^6 + … + i^(2n+2) =
1 + (i + i^2) * (1 + i^2 + i^4 + i^6 + … + i^n)
```

so you can half the number of summands in the right parenthesis at each step. Now there is no division, so you can perform modulo operations after each operation.
You can thus define something like

```
def modpowsum(a, n, m):
  """(1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + ... + a^n) mod m"""
  if n == 0:
    return 1
  if n == 1:
    return (1 + a) % m
  if n % 2 == 1:
    return ((1 + a) * modpowsum((a * a) % m, (n - 1) // 2, m)) % m
  return (1 + ((a + a * a) % m) * modpowsum((a * a) % m, n // 2 - 1, m)) % m
```

The whole computation can be seen at https://ideone.com/Xh0Fuf running some random and some not-so-random test cases against your implementation.

Comment: I am not sure if I was unclear in my explanation, or misunderstanding your answer. I realized this represents i^n, and I wanted i * k, i.e. the previous term. The kth value does not increase in power with each iteration. It's more like this: say i =3, k= 1, j = 5 and m = 10 then  (i * k + j) % m = (3*(1) + 5) % 10 = 8

Comment: And the next iteration on that based on the for loop would be (3*(8) + 5) % 10 = 9. Using your program above, although faster gives me incorrect output

Comment: @Zaruya, could you provide specific values for all `(i,j,m,k,n)` where you think that the formula from the first box doesn't work correctly, given that it is translated to Python as `(i ** n * k + (i ** n - 1) / (i - 1) * j) % m`

Comment: @SergGr it seems that I implemented the program incorrectly. Using the formula, you just gave I did in fact get the answer. However, it's still taking a while for the larger values

Comment: @SergGr It's just that modpowsum function does not seem to work

Comment: @Zaruya: I think you are misunderstanding my answer. When you compute `i*k` and that `k` is the result of some previous term involving multiplication with `i`, then this leads to the essentially exponential term there. And by squaring the term on each iteration, the number of iterations can be bounded by the bit length of `n` instead of its value. You can see that in the fact that each recursive call divides `n` by two. Have a look at the ideone link I now included, and toy with it to see whether that helps make my answer clearer.

Comment: @SergGr: Exponentiation with modulo at the very end will do a lot of the computation using floating point arithmetic, which usually is not something you want when working in some modulo ring. So while the formula makes sense mathematically, I'd rather not enter it like this into python. Division requires a field not just a ring, which in turn requires a prime modulus and some computation to get a multiplicative inverse. Thus the generic `modpowsum` (now that I fixed a mistake) is better.

Comment: @MvG my apologies, it seems that I was implementing it incorrectly all this time